# Prolog depth-first search?

Tags: prolog

I wrote the following Prolog code for depth first search:

```
dfs(OPEN,CLOSE,END):-
        OPEN=[],!,fail
        ;
            OPEN=[X|_],X=END,!,true
            ;
            getChildren(X,[],ChL),CLOSE2=[X|CLOSE],add(ChL,OPEN,CLOSE2,OPENF),
            dfs(OPENF,CLOSE2,END).

getChildren(X,ChL,ChLF):-
    parent(X,Ch),not(member(Ch,ChL)),!,ChL2=[Ch|ChL],
    getChildren(X,ChL2,ChLF)
    ;
    ChLF=ChL.


member(X,[X|_]).
member(X,[_|T]):-
    member(X,T).


add([],OPEN,_,OPENF):-OPENF=OPEN,!.
add(ChL,OPEN,CLOSE,OPENF):-
    ChL=[H|T],not(member(H,OPEN)),not(member(H,CLOSE)),!,
    OPEN2=[H|OPEN],add(T,OPEN2,CLOSE,OPENF)
    ;
    ChL=[_|T],add(T,OPEN,CLOSE,OPENF).
```

However, I get the following error:

```
the variable is not bounded in this clause  X
```

Comment: Your code follows the syntax of Prolog, but it does not read like a good Prolog program: it reads a lot more like a program in an imperative language. You can improve your program a lot simply by getting rid of the "cut" operator. This will also force you to rethink your use of the semicolon operator.

Comment: Is there a reason for redefining the built-in predicate, `member/2`? It's already part of ISO prolog.

Comment: can any one help me to understand this erro

Comment: This problem isn't stated clearly. What is the exact error message and what line or lines of code is it referring to? And how are you doing your query (what are you calling that generates the error)?

Comment: getChildren(X,ChL,ChLF):-                                                   when i first try it, its work but when i put it in the depth first search it does not work

Comment: You aren't providing enough information. What prolog interpreter are you using? And you haven't explained how you're calling your predicate. "When I first try it..." Try it how? And "When i put it in the depth first search..." what does that mean? Please explained exactly what you typed in and what the responses were.

Comment: visual prolog interpreter.  and parent defined in predicate part

Comment: @false sorry my mistake. I was trying to get to the bottom of the `parent` predicate and I misunderstood the OP's response as meaning that it was somehow part of that environment. I removed the tag.

Comment: sorry but this is my first time